# How do I join an object with particles, and keep the particles on only the one object?

Tags: particles

Just started using blender about a week ago. So I am creating a doughnut with sprinkles on it. I used emitter particles on my frosting. When I went to join the bread part of the donut and the frosting, the sprinkles combined with the the bread part also. I was wondering if there was any way to make it so it would not do this.

Comment: Try not to join "bread" and "icing" meshes. Use parenting instead.

Comment: hi, I guess frosting and sprinkles are a single object, now. Maybe you should separate them first, then you can join only frosting and bread, leaving sprinkles out? also why you need to do this, since bread and frosting are separate, why the need to join them?

Comment: I am exporting them into unreal engine 4.

Comment: Can you apply the sprinkles somehow so they become real (linked) objects?

Comment: I do not know, sorry I am very new to this.